# File couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it error

Tags: swift, macos

I have Googled and poked around Stack Overflow and can't seem to find a solution for this. I have:

```
let fileURL = URL( string: "file:///Users/me/file.txt" )    
var rawDataString: String 
var errorString: String?

do {
    rawDataString = try String( contentsOf: fileURL!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8 )
} catch let error as NSError {
    errorString = error.description
    print( errorString! )
    return
}
```

and it's erroring out with

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “file.txt” couldn’t
>   be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."

Permissions are read for all users:

```
$ ls -al file.txt
-rw-r--r--@ 1 me  staff  348306 Dec 13  2016 file.txt
```

Any ideas would be most welcome.

Comment: You need to turn off App Sandbox in your app target capabilities. Another option is present `NSOpenPanel` to let the user select the file.

Comment: Btw not related to your question but `String.Encoding` is redundant (inferred) and no need to cast the error to NSError `encoding: .utf8 )` and  `} catch { print(error)`

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm not seeing where to turn off App Sandbox in my scheme. Can you point me to it?

Comment: You can also use `URL` fileURLWithPath initializer. You just need to drop the url scheme file://.  `let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/me/file.txt" )`

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/19pgzpmtgr4a4t6/Screen%20Shot%202018-03-01%20at%2013.44.27.png?dl=1

Comment: you can also drop the txt file into your project and include it into your Bundle

Comment: @LeoDabus fileURLWithPath works beautifully, but I'm not sure about not casting the error to NSError--if I just do } catch let error { it gives Value of type 'Error' has no member 'description'

Comment: Just print(error) you can add localizedDescription but it is redundant

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Anyone coming across this thread, @LeoDabus pointed me to where to turn off sandbox, which worked:

[image]

He also cleaned up my code a bit:

```
let fileURL = URL( fileURLWithPath: "/Users/me/file.txt" )    
var rawDataString: String
var errorString: String?

do {
    rawDataString = try String( contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8 )
} catch let error as NSError {
    errorString = error.description
    rawDataString = ""
    return
}
```

Comment: Turning off App Sandbox wasn't an option available to me.  App Sandbox wasn't even listed.  Are there other causes for this?

Comment: That's odd @ScottyBlades--I just checked it for a project that I'm working on, and it's definitely there. If you click on the project name in the file selector window, the one on top of the tree with all your files, then you get a window with tabs General, Capabilities, Resource Tags, etc., and if you click on Capabilities, App Sandbox is up at the top. I'm using Xcode 9.3.1. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yea...in my project running Xcode 9.2 after clicking my project in the file navigator, targets my project, capabilities I see [iCloud, Push Notifications, Game Center, Wallet, Siri, Apple Pay, in-app purchases, maps, personal vpn, network extensions, hotspot configuration, multipath, near field communication tag reading etc. etc. etc. no sandbox.

Comment: Are you building for iOS? This is for a Mac app 

Answer (score 32):

**(For iOS)**

Sadly @Dribbler´s answer didn't work for me because I didn't have App Sandbox enabled and it still didn't work. In my case I used the UIDocumentPickerViewController and I was unable to access the file.

Adding `url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` before working with the file resolved the issue for me.

Here is an example of the `didPickDocumentsAt` delegate function from a UIDocumentPickerViewController:

```
guard let url = urls.first else {
      return
}
guard url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else { // Notice this line right here
     return
}
    
do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

After adding that line it worked for me.

Comment: Side note: It's missing the `url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` at the end.

Answer (score 5):

I actually was not able to get the preferred answers above to work for me in swift playground.

Another solution is just to create a `command line` app in Xcode. Then paste the above and it should work fine.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution According to Apple Docs**
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1779698-startaccessingsecurityscopedreso

```
extension ViewController : UIDocumentPickerDelegate{

func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {

    guard let url = urls.first else {return}

    if url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource(){

        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url){
            let filename = url.lastPathComponent
 
            print("Data Byte",data)
            print("filename",filename)
        }
        
        url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
    }

}
```

}